# TortoiseSVN копия сайта с интернета

Tags: svn

Каким образом можно сделать копию сайта НА SVN с интернета?
С локального компа просто нажать Checkout. А как быть когда сайт уже есть в интернете?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Абсолютно также. Только адрес уже будет не локальный, а интернетовский. И если там, в интернете, нет сервера SVN, то Вы никак не скопируете. Если только по ftp или как там еще можно.

*UPD1*:
Ну вот скриншоты, которые докажут, что это абсолютно также легко и одинаково. Может, вы не тот адрес указываете. Для примера, вот ссылка на один из оупенсурс проектов под SVN :
https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-framework/trunk
Попробуйте вы такой адрес поставить после того, как выберете на папке чекаут.

[image]

*UPD2*:
Для заливки на сервер и обновление ставить в боевое состояние - уже совершенно другое. Для этого есть система, которая устанавливается на сервере. `TeamCity` называется. [ВОТ](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/php/105895/) пример использования для PHP. Или, если на PHP не надо, то поищете для другого. И еще, она изначально делалась для организации эффективной коллективной работы над кодом приложений Java и .NET. Также она как-то настраивается для SVN. Как, не знаю, предоставляю искать вам. Знаю только как работать: Делаете checkout, затем заходите на `TeamCity` на своем хосте, и нажимаете на кнопку, чтобы вывести обновленный сайт на боевое состояние.

Comment: SVN в интернете. Что нужно сделать в TortoiseSVN чтобы добавить в SVN? Есть может какое руководство? Я сам не нашел, перегуглился

Comment: Вы сказали абсолютно так же. Локальные файлы закинуть в SVN - просто нажать на папку правой кнопкой мыши и выбрать действие, все. А интернетовские файлы как? ФТП клиенты не реагируют на правую кнопку мыхи.
Не могли бы вы просто подробней рассказать как это сделать :)

Comment: Антон, вы видимо не так поняли. С локального компа на SVN в интернете я могу заливать. У меня вопрос. Как заливать уже рабочий сайт, который в интернете, на SVN который тоже в интернете?